# Node / Express challenges with shared hosting

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get a Node app working on A2 Shared hosting.  Has anyone got any experience with getting node to work on A2 shared hosting?

My problem seems to be with Express - not even the simplest node test file runs, for example :-

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(`INDEX`);
});
app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
    res.send(`ABOUT`);
});
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
```

All I get is :-

Cannot GET /mysite1/

(where mysite1 is the name of the location / application I specified in the Node confirguration in the A2 Hosting control panel.

H

Comment: There are often severe limitations for running persistent servers like nodejs servers on shared hosting accounts.  You can read what A2 has to say about it here: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/making-persistent-node.js-applications and here https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-software/create-application-with-nodejs-selector.

Comment: You need to install nodejs first of all on your host. So I think your host provider doesn't support this.